# Algebraic Geometry question

Tags: algebraic-geometry, motivation

Why do we study projective normality of a projective variety ? Does it have anything to do with non-singularity ? Any other purpose to study this ?

Comment: Dear Jack, Projective normality gives an algebraic interpretation of a geometric property of linear systems on a variety: it says that the intersection of the variety with a complete linear system of hypersurfaces in projective space is again a complete linear system on the projectively normal variety.  (At least if the variety is non-singular.)  This is discussed in the wikipedia entry on this topic.  Regards, Matthew